# SQLite update query in Titanium Alloy

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, titanium-alloy

Hello fellow Titanium devs.

I am new to Titanium Alloy development, but not to Javascript. I have run into problems with the SQLite update query in my Titanium Alloy app and seek your help.

My controller js file is as follows.

```
var items = [];
var db = Ti.Database.open('listDB');
//db.file.setRemoteBackup(false);

db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS liststatus(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, value INTEGER);');
var my_result_set = db.execute('SELECT * FROM liststatus');
var records = my_result_set.rowCount;

Ti.API.info(records);
if(records == 0){
    db.execute('INSERT INTO liststatus(id, name, value) VALUES (1, "Node #1", 0)');
    db.execute('INSERT INTO liststatus(id, name, value) VALUES (2, "Node #2", 0)');
    db.execute('INSERT INTO liststatus(id, name, value) VALUES (3, "Node #3", 1)');
}

var rows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM liststatus');

while (rows.isValidRow())
{
    if(rows.fieldByName('value') == 1){
        var truVal = "true";
    }else{
        var truVal = "false";
    }
    items.push({"id": rows.fieldByName('id'), "label":{text: rows.fieldByName('name')},"switchVal":{value: truVal}, "template": "title_only"});
    rows.next();
};

$.dynamicListView.sections[0].setItems(items);

var itemsUpdate = [];

function outputState(e){
    var section = $.dynamicListView.sections[e.sectionIndex];
    var item = section.getItemAt(e.itemIndex);
    //itemsUpdate.push({"id": item.id, "value": e.value});
    var val = e.value;
    var itemId = item.id;
    //db.execute('UPDATE liststatus SET value=? WHERE id=?',1,1);
    db.execute('UPDATE liststatus SET value=? WHERE id=?',val,itemId);
}
rows.close();
db.close();
```

My view xml looks like this.

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container" id="dbWin">
        <!--<Toolbar top="0" platform="ios">
            <Items>
                <Button id="button" onClick="saveData">Save</Button>
            </Items>
     </Toolbar>-->
        <ListView id="dynamicListView">
            <Templates>
                <ItemTemplate name="title_only">
                    <View layout="horizontal">
                        <Label class="label" bindId="label"/>
                        <Switch bindId="switchVal" onChange="outputState" />
                    </View>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </Templates>
            <ListSection/>
        </ListView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

The problem is that the update query does not fire at all when the switch toggle is changed. How do I get around this? What is it that I am not doing right here? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Regards.

Shreerang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it's not firing, but I would start by adding Ti.Api.info to the function and see if it's being called.

Now, you have a few basic errors in your code (ones that are related to javascript rather than Titanium) that could cause problems and memory leaks.

1. you are creating the db variable outside the scope of the function (scope of the controller). since it's being used inside the function, the js engine will keep a reference to it - and by that would keep it in memory - so there's a memory leak.
2. You execute some code, and close you db. When you call that function you db connection should already be closed - I would look for errors in Titanium console about that update execution.

what you should do is create, open, and than close a new instance of your db inside the scope of the function.

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Things about the memory leaks - Yes we will fix those, once we have the functionality in place. What helped is the creation of a new instance of the DB. Thanks for your help!